# PermissionError only raised the first time - pd.ExcelWriter.save()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to execute the following snippet:

```py
while 1:
    print("test")
    try:
        tentativa += 1
        writer.save()
        print("test 2")
        break
    except PermissionError:
        print("test 3")
        if tentativa > 3:
            sys.exit(-1)
        input(f"(Tentativa {tentativa} de 3) Tecle ENTER para tentar novamente... ")
```

The *writer* object is a *pd.ExcelWriter*, using *xlsxwriter* as engine.
When you use save() method, it tries to save the Excel file into the directory i informed. No problem with this. But, when the excel file is open, this method raises a *PermissionError*, because it cannot overwrite the file. No problem with this too...

But if i keep the file open, and retry running the same method, it doesn't raises the exception, so the *except* clause has nothing to catch, it prints "test" and "test 2" and breaks the while...

1st cycle: "test" and "test 3" (File is open)

2nd cycle: "test" and "test 2" (File is open)

**Anyone knows why this method isn't raising the exception on the second cycle of while? Is it a bug?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked out the Workbook object from *xlsxwriter*, and it has the following code:

```
def close(self):
        """
        Call finalization code and close file.

        Args:
            None.

        Returns:
            Nothing.

        """
        if not self.fileclosed:
            self.fileclosed = 1
            self._store_workbook()
```

As the instance in memory is the same on the second cycle of while, `workbook.fileclosed` is still 1 (True), so the method `_store_workbook()` doesn't gets called. As this goes on, no exception is raised.

So i made an workaround for this method, which was the addition of `writer.book.fileclosed` line.

The result:

```
while 1:
    print("test")
    writer.book.fileclosed = 0
    try:
        tentativa += 1
        writer.save()
        print("test 2")
        break
    except PermissionError:
        print("test 3")
        if tentativa > 3:
            sys.exit(-1)
        input(f"(Tentativa {tentativa} de 3) Tecle ENTER para tentar novamente... ")
```

This snippet works well.

Not sure what is the intention of having the *fileclosed* variable though.